# How can I remove characters of text in one line before a specific character?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

How can I remove characters of text in one line before a specific character?

I want to remove characters to the left of the first letter "F"

Example:

```
null###F01|54646466|00K4234001|IFD|1990101
null###F02|54646499|00K4234001|TFS|1990101
null###F03|03232432|00RWEREW01|ZAI|1990101
```

The result must be

```
F01|54646466|00K4234001|IFD|1990101
F02|54646499|00K4234001|TFS|1990101
F03|03232432|00RWEREW01|ZAI|1990101
```

I 'm trying with `awk -F"F" '{print "F"$2}'` but it does not work.

Comment: ...why is IFD made IFS?

Comment: IFS is a data example, Im corrected data

Comment: `sed 's/^[^F]*//' datafile`

Comment: What about reading the man page or any of the gazillon blog posts about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -o 'F.*'
```

or (we need more than 30 chars)

```
perl -pe 's!.*?F!F!'
```

Answer (score 7):

If your input *all* looks like that, then the most efficient solution is most likely:

```
cut -d\# -f4- <<\IN
null###F01|54646466|00K4234001|IFD|1990101
null###F02|54646499|00K4234001|TFS|1990101
null###F03|03232432|00RWEREW01|ZAI|1990101
IN
```

I use a heredocument above to demonstrate, but you can just use `cut -d\# -f4- <infile >outfile`. You could also use `cut -c8- <in >out` *(which, if I'm honest, is probably actually the most efficient way)*. Either way...

#### OUTPUT

```
F01|54646466|00K4234001|IFD|1990101
F02|54646499|00K4234001|TFS|1990101
F03|03232432|00RWEREW01|ZAI|1990101
```

Comment: cool (+1). Why `<<\IN` and not `<<IN` ?

Comment: @JJao - because a quoted delimiter protects the contents against expansion. I guess it is irrelevant here, but it is a habit only not to quote when i definitely mean for something to get expanded.